# IQueryable Lambda Expression for every Nth date

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda, iqueryable

I have a calendar table that contains a series of dates, and I'm trying to write a query that gives me every N dates.  I can do this in SQL without difficulty, but when writing it in a `IQueryable` with a `Where` condition, I can't seem to get it to work.

As an example, I can do something similar to this in SQL to get every third date:

```
Select _date 
from Calendar 
where datediff(day, startdate, _date) % 3 = 0
```

but a similar `IQueryable` lambda expression throws a `System.ArgumentException` (when the query is executed)

```
var q = dbcontext.Calendar
                 .Where( c => (c._date - startdate).Days % 3 == 0);
```

Is there some other way this could be written to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
var q = dbcontext.Calendar
                 .Where(c => EF.Functions.DateDiffDay(startdate, c._date) % 3 == 0);
```

Comment: Thank you!  I should have said I'm using EF6, but your answer helped me find `DbFunctions.DiffDays`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that with lambda expressions in EF, but you can use [raw queries](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/raw-sql) and use the sql query you already wrote (or use a stored procedure) if you wish.